# No module named 'pymysql' FLASK в то время, когда он есть

Tags: mysql, база-данных, flask

Уже не знаю сколько разбираюсь с этой проблемой...
Установлен и mysqlclient и pymysql, но все равно выдает ошибку
В терминале ввожу команды
from database import db
db.create_all()

**database.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://sql2227827:aK5%rU9!@sql2.freemysqlhosting.net/aK5%rU9!'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Comments(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32))


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 963, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 955, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 896, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 559, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = sqlalchemy.create_engine(info, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 424, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 81, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\pymysql.py", line 62, in dbapi
    return __import__('pymysql')
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы явно запускаете фласк не в виртуальном окружении

Comment: Как это не в виртуальном окружении? Именно в нем.

Comment: Текст ошибки явно говорит о том, что именно не в нем :) Расскажите, как вы запускаете-то

Comment: Добавил скриншот того, как запускаю виртуальное окружение

Comment: Тогда действительно странная ситуация. А покажите всё содержимое каталога Scripts?

Comment: добавил скриншот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло добавить pymysql.
PS. Работаю в PyCharm

```
import pymysql
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://sql2227827:aK5%rU9!@sql2.freemysqlhosting.net/sql2227827'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

def add_user():
    user = User(email='vokler98@gmail.com', password_hash='82911493p')
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    add_user()
```

Comment: То есть вчера pymysql не импортировался, а сегодня вдруг стал импортироваться? Это всё ооооооочень странно

Comment: Я забыл его подключить - pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb() ...

Comment: Менее странно не стало, потому что, судя по скриншоту в вопросе, у вас строчка `import pymysql` должна выдавать ошибку